# Open contact activity when a specified input-field is pressed

Tags: android-activity, android-webview, android-contacts, input-field

I want to launch an contact-activity when a input-field (text) in a **webview** is pressed. Not sure how I can do this. Have tried to search the web but the only results I get is how to launch a filebrowser when a "input-file-field" is pressed.. And it seems like Android have an option that is exactly for that purpose, but not when another input-type is pressed?

What I actually want to do is;

when the input field  is pressed, I want to give the user an option to launch the contact manager (or something similar) to choose one or more contacts from its contactlist.

Then fill the input-field with the contacts emails, separated with commas.

Is it possible to do this? Any idea what I should search the web for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Added a new class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class JSFromPage {

    Context mContext;

    JSFromPage(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void openContact() {

        Intent intent = (Intent) new Intent( mContext, ListContacts.class );
        mContext.startActivity( intent );

    }

}
```

And uses this is my WebView class:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSFromPage(this), "Android");
```

And this is my html on the input:

```
onclick="Android.openContact();"
```

Then i created the class "ListContacts.class" with a new activity.